# Create Ubuntu LiveCD that boots into RAM and run a custom script

Tags: scripts, live-cd

I have a simple question. Is there any way I could create ubuntu LiveCD that would boot into RAM and run a simple shell script that I have?
I tried using CUBIC, but with CUBIC I am being able to install the ISO into hard disk and not into RAM.
Need to install the ubuntu into RAM and run a script. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: what do you need to do? Why can't you just run off the live CD and run the script there? Also "installing" and "to RAM" doesn't really make sense, since RAM gets erased as soon as you shut down.

Comment: Hmm using tools like cubic is all fine and dandy but it does prevent you from understanding what you are doing.Yes, what you want is possible: mount the ISO using a squasfs and you can add anything you want. (files in /etc/skel/ will get added to Desktop for instance) you can alter gsettings, you can alter default theme and add scripts. But ... explaining it will take more than a few lines ;) Back in the old days: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679 It will work for current OS but specific examples will have changed... a lot.

Comment: I am working on a process that needs to run  a script, send some information generated by that script and erase the OS, that is why I need it in RAM.

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind, I will look into the direction you suggested.